# Get length of routes (react-navigation)

Tags: react-navigation

[length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZd1n.png)

I used react-navigation and I wanted to get the length, but I failed.
I want to know how to use it correctly, can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get a good solution to this?